# Step-through in VS without VS having focus

Tags: visual-studio

I find myself working with GUI code where the GUI program needs input focus and remain the topmost window, but whenever I'm debugging with VS stepping-through with F5/F10/F11 requires that VS has focus.

Is it possible to have VS intercept the F-keys whilst the debugee has focus? If VS doesn't have this functionality I imagine it should be possible to write a simple program or VS add-in that has a keyboard book and commands the debugger accordingly - has anyone developed such a program?

I'm working with a GUI test automation framework that sends mouse-clicks and other events by moving the cursor. When the debugee program is out of focus any click on its surface brings the main window forward but does not activate any controls, but the automation framework assumes that its focus of the application will never be interrupted. So if I set a breakpoint before a click that is meant to open the File menu then the click that is sent will only restore the debugee's focus and not open the File menu (if that makes sense).

I've done some searching but couldn't find anything immediately.

Comment: What GUI flavour is your app? winforms/WPF?

Comment: I've amended my question to describe why focus-loss is a problem.

Comment: Which automation framework are you using? Its a long time since I've used them but I think that one of them (possibly White) runs everything on a separate desktop to avoid any interaction with what is going on.

Comment: It's a proprietary internal system and I don't have access to the source code. I'm sorry I can't provide more information. Can you tell me more about this alternative-desktop system?

Comment: Hmm, couldn't find what I read before, this points you into how to do it http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/how-to-implement-virtual-desktop/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to maintain focus? Have you specific hooks in the GotFocus/LostFocus?

I've had problems before with the Paint event being called as soon as F5 was hit causing the debugger to show again and therefore requiring another repaint. I got around these simply by arranging my windows so they didn't overlap. I'm pretty sure the LostFocus/GotFocus pair also don't fire when the windows are arranged this way too.

Comment: I've amended my question to describe why focus-loss is a problem.